# How to pass in props in react directly as constants?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to write the type inside props which are being passed directly as constants e.g. `const ComponentName = ({tasks: TaskType[]}) => {return (<>{tasks[0]}</>)}`?

My TaskType is stored as an interface in another file. I don't want to use Props and write the name of each prop directly but typescript is giving me lots of error.

the files can be found here https://codesandbox.io/s/great-pare-m8ei2?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this has very little to do with reactjs and everything to do with parameter syntax in typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to type functional components is using the React.FC type from react. SOmething like this:

```
const AddTaskForm: React.FC<{tasks: TaskType[], setTasks: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TaskType[]>>}> = ( {tasks, setTasks} ) => {
...
}

export default AddTaskForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where you keep the types close to the arguments

```
(_: {
  tasks: TaskType[],
  setTasks: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TaskType[]>>
})
```

It should be noted that this syntax is global to typescript function arguments, and has nothing in particular to do with ReactJS